# Getting "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" error on Chrome. Works fine on Safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I get the error on any POST requests (for logging in, or posting data through forms) using Chrome browser. You can try it out at http://52.xx.xx.xxx/users/login. Just use any username / password - should give you:

> The change you wanted was rejected.

Here is a snippet of the error from the logs:

```
W, [2017-07-10T08:40:16.486974 #11349]  WARN -- : Can't verify CSRF token authenticity 
I, [2017-07-10T08:40:16.487259 #11349]  INFO -- : Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) 
D, [2017-07-10T08:40:16.487526 #11349] DEBUG -- : User excluded error: #<ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken>
```

The exact same login request, or other post requests go through on Safari. The site has a self signed certificate. So, I've changed Chrome settings to trust the certificate and accept cookies.

Please suggest what else i should look for and what other logs might be helpful in debugging the issue. I've looked at quite a few SO threads over the past 2 days and couldn't find anything that solved my issue.

**Edit:**
Removed the IP address to prevent unnecessary traffic to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i got around the problem by using https instead of http at the start of the URL. As expected, chrome throws up the security related warnings, but adding an exception allows post requests to go through without errors.

Safari was somehow able to redirect my requests(with http or nothing at all) to https because of which it was working. Tried with http on safari and ended up with the same issue.

Marking this as solved - since the original observation doesn't hold anymore. I need to figure how to make the http and non http requests redirect to https on my nginx backend and that should fix the issue.