# ruby on rails allow embedding of your website in other sites using frame_ancestors content security policy or X-Frame-Options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, iframe, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

I am trying to allow others embed pages from my rails app on many websites. I can get it to work in Chrome and Firefox using X-Frame-Options. Is there a content security policy that is equivalent
`response.headers['X-Frame-Options'] = "ALLOW-FROM *"`

Here is the bit  using X-Frame-Options

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def embed
    response.headers['X-Frame-Options'] = "ALLOW-FROM *"
    @company = People.new
  end
end
```

But does not work, when using content security policy in both Chrome and Google when i use content security policy

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  content_security_policy do |p|
    p.frame_ancestors "self", "*"
  end

  def embed
    @company = People.new
  end
end
```

When using Content Security Policy, it throws this error:

```
Refused to frame 'http://localhost:3000/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors self".
```

and this is an example of the embed code:

```
  <iframe src="http://localhost:3000/people/embed"></iframe>
```

and this is another one I tried:

```
  <iframe src="/people/embed"></iframe>
```

**Update**

With content-security policy, this works only on Firefox:

```
content_security_policy do |p|
  p.frame_ancestors 'self', "*"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern Chrome and Firefox do not support `ALLOW-FROM` key in the `X-Frame-Options` header. You can publish `X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM ###` or `X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM http://example.com` - they restrict nothing, headers with `ALLOW-FROM` key be just ignore by browsers.

If you wish to allow iframing for unlimited domains, it's easier not to publish `X-Frame-Options` header (and `frame-ancestors` directive) at all.

If you have a counted set of allowed domains you can use CSP header with `frame-ancestors domain1 domain2 ... domainN;`.

> When using Content Security Policy, it throws this error: `... because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors self"`

This error means that you really published `frame-ancestors 'self'`, not `frame-ancestors 'self' *` as expected.
Maybe you published two different CSP headers at the same time, maybe you have error in code. You can [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629) what CSP header you actually got in browser.

**Note 1**: `'self'` token should be a single-quoted - use `"'self'"` string in code.

**Note 2**: `'self'` token commonly covers standard ports 80/443 only, it's not cover  `http://localhost:3000` (it's browser's depend). An asterisk `*` does cover any port numbers.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, from the controller, I tried **response.headers.delete "X-Frame-Options"** , but the form submission only works for Firefox and fails for Chrome unless i add to the controller **skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token**

Comment: It's not a CSP-related issue. `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` in Chrome related to `http;` usage instead of `https:` Firefox [somehow able to redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003696/getting-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-error-on-chrome-works-fine-on-sa/45004133#45004133) http to https. but Chrome does not. People commonly [solve this](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/2734) using `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` in Nginx, but firstly you have to try to clear Crome browser cache and coockie,